# Add functions in JDL Jhipster for angular project

Tags: angular, jhipster, jdl

For Example I want to add functions like onChange, focosout, onblur, onClick with passing extra parameter in jdl as

```
entity Student {
    studentId Integer,
    studentRegNum String maxlength(50) (onChange)="SomeChangeAction()",
    firstName String maxlength(50),
}
```

and the output should be like in 
**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" (onChange)="SomeChangeAction()"
                            id="field_firstName" formControlName="firstName"   />
```

**TS file **

```
SomeChangeAction() {
}
```

Is it possible to add like this?

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible, you must code it yourself manually